# OpenGL Sleep or delay between each frame?

Tags: opengl, sleep, glut

So, I'm trying to make a delay on this program, between each drawing.
I tried using Sleep(), but it gives me an error if used on the draw() function, and if used elsewhere, it makes no effect.

Xcode compiles the file, but points me to this error while running:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__semwait_signal:
0x7fff8fd7937c:  movl   $33554766, %eax
0x7fff8fd79381:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x7fff8fd79384:  syscall
0x7fff8fd79386:  jae    0x7fff8fd7938d            ; __semwait_signal + 17
0x7fff8fd79388:  jmpq   0x7fff8fd7a4c8            ; cerror
0x7fff8fd7938d:  ret    
0x7fff8fd7938e:  nop    
0x7fff8fd7938f:  nop
```

Code:

```
void draw()
{
GLint width;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glPointSize(10);

int x=0; int y=0;
glBegin(GL_POINTS);


for(x=0; x<500; x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<500; y++)
    {
        glColor3f(rand()%255,rand()%255, rand()%255);
        glVertex2i(rand()%500,rand()%500);
    }
}
sleep(500);
glEnd();
glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){


glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
glutCreateWindow ("Trabalho de Modelagem e Simulação de Processos");


glutDisplayFunc(draw);
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
gluOrtho2D (0.0f, 500.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f);
glutIdleFunc(draw);
glutMainLoop();
return 1;
```

}

Comment: Watch your capitalisation.  If this is for Windows, it's `Sleep`, not `sleep`.  Also, I wouldn't put it inside the immediate-mode stuff.  Put it after the `glFlush()`.  If you are getting "an error", it's helpful to show us the error.  Doing so will also help you get into the routine of *reading* the error.

Comment: Hmm, my apologies.  I didn't originally see the error, or maybe you edited it in just after I read the question.  Try my suggestion about removing the sleep from the immediate-mode section.  My guess is that your kernel doesn't want to sleep while you're in the middle of passing data into GL.

Comment: Yeah, using sleep or Sleep rather gives me error or makes no effect while running.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it doesn't solve your immediate problem, you should consider restructuring your program. First of all, you should make OpenGL calls only from the display callback you register with GLUT, not from the idle callback, which means: Don't register `draw` as the idle function. Instead you should register a dedicated function that calls `glutPostRedisplay` or `glutPostRedisplay` itself as idle function. Any kind of long term delays (where long term means anything longer than 10ms) should be implemented using a timer, so that the program stays interactive.

Comment: After restructuring your code as advised above, look up glutTimerFunc. It will allow you to call glutPostRedisplay at whatever rate you want

Comment: @HughFisher: I know glutTimerFunc. I'd even say I know it better than you. Because apparently you don't seem to know, that glutTimerFunc is not providing a reliable timing source, and using it to triggering display redraw may cause stuttering and/or an uneven framerate. Take some high resolution clock (Windows: [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx), \*nix/Linux: [clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,…)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) and use it to measure deviation from requested timer interval and variance. It's bad.

Comment: I don't know how accurate the original poster needs the timer to be. If glutTimerFunc is "good enough" then it works cross platform and doesn't require any additional libraries or code